# How to use fft to detect environment

Tags: java, android, audio, fft

guys.  I am currently doing a project to detect which environment(e.g. on car,on bus, on trains, on street, in canteens,) are you in based on the audio recorded in that environment.

Basically I will record a wav first, and do FFT, and analyze on the frequency domain.
The software should be developed as an Android app.

I have read papers about HMM, MFCC, but I believe they are too complicated for just detecting a few environment.

Any idea or suggestion is welcomed!  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working on a similar project several years ago, and trying to know the users current vehicle from the information collected from multiple sensors like accelerometer, gyroscope and GPS.

In that project, i used FFT, decision tree and HMM. I think only audio + FFT is far not enough, FFT can extract several features on frequency domain from audio data, but only these cannot distinguish the environment.

My suggestion is choosing a proper algorithm in data mining to train a strong model, and use HMM or other methods to do time series analysis.

Comment: Hi faylon, many thanks for you reply!  May I ask how you build your model and train the model, and how to use HMM to do time series analysis?  I am sorry that I don't have very strong knowledge basis for this...

Comment: Ok, First of all, you need to collect data from sensors in different environment, by different people. secondly you need to extract some distinguish feature from all these data, just like speed, acceleration, frequency energy, variance of them and many others. Thirdly, choose one or several algorithm in data mining to build a model base on these features and data.

Comment: Then you can use this model to do classification. Hmm is used for time series analysis, you can simply use a state transition probability table to predict current state from past states.